# Test flutter project couldn't run on a selected android emulator from my devices list

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I have setup flutter on a new pc and when I try to [select the android emulator and run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTXRU.png) the default starting flutter project, it gives a
["Lost connection to the device"
"db.exe: device 'emulator-5554' not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeX2a.png)
error on the run console.

I ran the `flutter doctor` command to check for issues and [everything looks fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu0l4.png)

I also ran the `flutter devices` command from the command prompt to check a list of devices but [I couldn't see the emulator that is available on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axUNz.png)

Comment: Android studio? A restart might help.

Comment: I have tried but it didn't help.

Comment: What about deleting the emulator and trying with a new one?